# Discrete Math Logical Equivalence

Tags: logic

x∧ ∼ y → ∼ z is logically equivalent to x ∧ z → y.

I can't figure it out, especially the negations are throwing me off.

Comment: Have you thrown this in a truth table?

Comment: Your expressions have two interpretations and need parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\equiv$ denote the logical equivalence. Consider two cases:

1. Suppose that $\neg x$, i.e. $x$ is $\mathtt{false}$, then both $x \land \neg y \to \neg z$ and $x \land z \to y$ are true, so
   $$(x \land \neg y \to \neg z)\equiv \mathtt{true} \equiv (x \land z \to y).$$
2. Suppose that $x$, that is, $x$ is $\mathtt{true}$, then
   $$(x \land \neg y \to \neg z)\equiv (\neg y \to \neg z) \equiv (z \to y) \equiv (x \land z \to y).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you so much, I just couldn't see the contrapositive!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to keep in mind that for statements $p,q$, the implication $p\to q$ is [logically equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) to $\neg p\vee q$. Substituting $(x\wedge\neg y)\to \neg z$, we then have:
$$ \neg(x\wedge\neg y)\vee (\neg z) = (\neg x\vee y)\vee \neg z,$$
where we've used De Morgan's Law: $\neg (p\wedge q)  = \neg p\vee \neg q$. Manipulating the last expression a little bit should get you to the logical form of $(x\wedge z)\to y$, which I'll leave to you (just write out the goal form and it should be clear what you need to do).

Answer (score 0):

$
(x\wedge \neg y) \to \neg z 
\\\Updownarrow \text{implication equivalence}
\\ \neg (x\wedge \neg y)\vee z 
\\ \Updownarrow \text{DeMorgan's Law}
\\ \underline{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
\\ \Updownarrow \text{Commutivity and Association}
\\ \underline{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
\\ \Updownarrow \text{DeMorgan's Law}
\\ \underline{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
\\ \Updownarrow \text{Implication Equivalence}
\\ (x\wedge z) \to y
$